# Creating ERD and SQL tables based on the ERD

Tags: sql, database-design, erd

I have an assignment to create an ERD from a story given and then make tables and build a db with the information given.

The story is:

There is a real estate company:

- Houses for sale are located at a specific Neighborhood.
- Each neighborhood is part of a city (as we know, in a city there are many neighborhoods)
- Each house is from a house type, such as: villa, apartment, penthouse, etc.
- Each house has an owner which is a customer of the company
- A sale (of a house) is made to a new owner (customer of the company) and in a sale a customer can buy only one house
- A sale is made by a salesman (a company worker)
- Each salesman specializes in different house types, and sometimes there are several salesmen that specialize in the same house types

The ERD I managed to come up with looks like this:

[image: Erd]

The tables I've managed to build are:

[image: Tables]

I`m pretty sure I got some of the tables wrong,starting from the ERD.

Would really appreciate some help with setting the correct tables before I create my database.

Comment: This question neatly illustrates the difference between two different models and their diagrams.  The top diagram is an ERD.  The bottom diagram is a relational schematic.  Well done.  There is one difference between your diagramming and mine.  When I learned ER modeling, you put the attributes in the ERD.  This makes analysis more complete and makes design less burdensome.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--not all terms/notations are standard & we don't know exactly what algorithm/method you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your textbook. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1):

I carefully checked you design, and it is true that some improvements are needed to properly fit your use case.

The following assumptions are properly implemented (however field names could be refined) :

- *Houses for sale are located at a specific Neighborhood*
  => 1-N relationship between `Neighborhood.NeighborhoodID` and `House.NeighborhoodID`
- *Each neighborhood is part of a city (as we know, in a city there are many neighborhoods)*
  => 1-N relationship between `City.CityID` and `House.CityID`
- *Each house is from a house type, such as: villa, apartment, penthouse, etc.*
  => 1-N relationship between `HouseType.HouseTypeID` and `House.HouseTypeID`

Following assumptions are NOT properly implemented in your schema :

- *Each house has an owner which is a customer of the company*
  =>This is a 1-N relationship. You need to create a new field in `House`, called `CustomerID`, that refers to `Customer.CustomerID`. Also, you need to create a new table, `Company`, that stores the Company information (don't store it in the `Customer` table !). A field called `CompanyID` must be created in table `Customer` that references the primary key of the `Company` table. You should not have a `HouseID` column in the `Customer` table.
- *A sale (of a house) is made to a new owner (customer of the company) and in a sale a customer can buy only one house*
  => The `Sale` table will contain one record per sale. It references the `CustomerID` and the `SalesManID` (see further). You should not have a `SalesID` column in the `Customer` table.
- *A sale is made by a salesman (a company worker)*
  => the `SalesMan` table should have a `CompanyID` field that references the `Company` table
- *Each salesman specializes in different house types, and sometimes there are several salesmen that specialize in the same house types* => the `SalesMan` table should have a `HouseTypeID` field that references the `HouseType` table. Table `SalesManToHouseType` should be dropped

Another remark is that you should simplify the names of the fields. There is no need to prefix the field names with the name of the table, as fields belong to tables already... This only make sense when dealing with foreign key, where it is a good pratice to put the target table name in the referencing field name.

Example for table `House` :

```
ID              -- not HouseID !
HouseTypeID     -- foreign key to field ID in table HouseType
NeighborhoodID  -- foreign key to field ID in table Neighborhood
CustomerID      -- foreign key to field ID in table Customer
Address
NumRooms
...
```

Example for table `HouseType` :

```
ID               -- not HouseTypeID !
Name             -- not HouseTypeName !
Description
```